# Winforms DataGridView UI does not update

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, asynchronous

I am working on a application which downloads using

```
1) Parallel.ForEach(linklist, x => DownloadAsync(x)); 
2) webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(link.Url));  

class Link 
{
 string url;
 string result;
 int progress;
}
```

and updates the datagridview using INotifyPropertyChanged.

The problem is that the download is real fast, the datagridview updates first row, then the UI does not update, but then on moving the mouse cursor on datagridview rows one by one each row updates values.

I don't understand where I am missing anything.

please any suggestings, thank you in advance.

EDIT: Async does not block the GUI, so i am not using background thread.

Comment: So you've set the the list as the DataSource for the DataGridView and the list is an ObservableCollection?

Comment: BindingSource is DataSource, which get the LinkList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you don't show your code, I assume you are updating UI elements from backgroud thread, which is something you should never do. If you are targeting WinForms you need to use `BackgroundWorker` or `Control.Invoke`.

[BackgroundWorker Component Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx)
[How to: Implement a Form That Uses a Background Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waw3xexc.aspx)
[How can I update my user interface from a thread that did not create it?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx)

Comment: Async does not block the GUI, no I am not using backgroundworker, same thread

Comment: @Milan Aditya - right, Async does not block the GUI, but when async calls back it calls back in non-UI thread, right? So you are updating datagrid data source from non-UI thread. BackgroundWorker guarantees that callback will happen in the UI thread.

Comment: yeah u r right, but what i am doing is i have set dataGridView1.DataSource = _BindingSource; on form_load, then it is updated automatically using the INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: DataGrid is subscribed to changes in your list, so when you are updating the list you are accessing datagrid from non-UI thread, which can lead to unpredicted results.

Comment: Alex thank you for your reply, but i must tell you there is some problem with datagridview or something i am missing completly, try and update datagridview bind to bindingsource and object with INotifyPropertyChanged it will not work, just try a simple for loop adding numbers, on button click on the same UI thread

Comment: Try using `BindingList<T>` as your source. If you do this, you will see the updates. But it will likely crash, when `BindingList<T>` is updated from the non-UI thread.

Comment: BindingList<T> Works good, thank you Alex for your answer and time.

Answer (score -1):

Your objects, being bound, need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.